# Sort Skew-Symmetric Tridiagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra, python, skew-symmetric-matrices, schur-decomposition

Suppose I have a skew-symmetric tridiagonal matrix of the from
\begin{equation}
M = \begin{pmatrix}0 & \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots\\ 
               -\lambda_1 & 0 &\lambda_2 & 0 &0 & \cdots\\
                0 & -\lambda_2 & 0 & \lambda_3 & 0 & \cdots\\
                0 & 0 & -\lambda_3 & 0 & \lambda_4 & \cdots\\
                \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
with $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}, \ge0$ and $i\in [1,...,N]$. In my case, such a matrix is the result of performing real Schur decomposition via scipy.linalg.schur in python (for some reason it does not return them ordered).

**The question:**
Is there a way to come up with a matrix $\Lambda$ such that $\Lambda M \Lambda^T$ is again skew-symmetric tridiagonal but with $\lambda$s ordered (say smallest at top left)?